# How to see PM2 restart history (node-pm2)

Tags: pm2

Is it possible to see the restart log/history with PM2 app?

I saw my nodeJS app restarted a few times but no clue when.

I've checked pm2 documentation but no luck.

Comment: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PM2 logs are streamed into the file ˜/.pm2/pm2.log

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command: `pm2 logs` for an output of all logs, relating to running apps and their error logs.

The first log file in the window will be the default PM2 ones, for this kind of information.